# How to upload multiple files angular 7/8 using Queue with progress bar and create main progress bar for all files

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to upload multiple files in Angular 7/8 using queue with creating one progress bar to upload all files.

Comment: Please provide more information on what have you tried so far or researched. There may be libraries to help you with your question and/or tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

You have different libraries that are available for this.

Have a look to [the ngx-upload library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wkoza/ngx-upload) (demo available [here](https://ngx-upload.github.io/simple-material/material)).

Comment: @Amit Viradiya: There's no need to start coding from scratch as you will probably need a lot of time. Many libraries are available to achieve the desired functionality. You could also take a look at https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/uploads/upload/

Comment: I need all file upload button single click and showing in the queue process. Please guide me.